# How can i access list elements in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am parsing xml from web service, i want to use xml values as a arraylist

```
 eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_NAME) values are  Traffic , Satellite , Hybrid , Satellite 2

 eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_URL) values are  url1 , url2 , url3, url4
```

`Lyr_LAYER_TYPE` and `Lyr_FIELD` has 4  elements

```
         List<String> LayerNames = new ArrayList<String>();

         for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

        Node nNode = nl.item(i);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            LayerNames.add(0, eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_NAME).item(0).getTextContent());
            LayerNames.add(1,eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_URL).item(0).getTextContent());
            LayerNames.add(2,eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_LAYER_TYPE).item(0).getTextContent());
            LayerNames.add(3,eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_FIELD).item(0).getTextContent());

        }

    }
```

Layer values are coming rapidly. But when i use get to access elements in arraylist it always return `Lyr_NAME` elements, then when i write `LayerNames[0]` Android Studio didn't resolve type. 
My log is;

```
    Log.e("Array List Result",LayerNames.get(0));
```

My question is how can i access to `Lyr_URL` , `Lyr_TYPE` or `Lyr_FIELD` ;?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get in List. You can use Map.

```
Map<String,String> LayerNames = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nl.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                LayerNames.put(Lyr_NAME, eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_NAME).item(0).getTextContent());
                LayerNames.put(Lyr_URL,eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_URL).item(0).getTextContent());
                LayerNames.put(Lyr_LAYER_TYPE,eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_LAYER_TYPE).item(0).getTextContent());
                LayerNames.put(Lyr_FIELD,eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_FIELD).item(0).getTextContent());
            }
        }
```

Log.e("Map Result",LayerNames.get(Lyr_URL));

Answer (score 0):

You neet to write `get` functions into `Lyr_NAME` classes' and return the attributes of the class with that functions. Than, you should add the same functions for the own attributes of `Lyr_URL`. You can just simply:

```
LayerNames.get(0).getLyr_URL().getURL1()
LayerNames.get(0).getTraffic() 
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

By populating arraylist with index, you are overwriting the existing elements and hence you will just left with last elements in the xml if there are multiple tags. Instead you should do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Node nNode = nl.item(i);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        LayerNames.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_NAME).item(0).getTextContent());
        LayerNames.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_URL).item(0).getTextContent());
        LayerNames.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_LAYER_TYPE).item(0).getTextContent());
        LayerNames.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName(Lyr_FIELD).item(0).getTextContent());

    }
}
```

And then you could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<LayerNames.size(); i+=4) {
    for (int j = i; j< i+4;j++) {
         Log.e("Array List Result", LayerNames.get(j));
    }
}
```

if you think it's just going to be once, then you could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i<LayerNames.size(); i+=4) {
         Log.e("Array List Result", LayerNames.get(j));
}
```

It will print layer name followed by url followed by layer type followed by field.